# There's an easy way to load csv rows into an Heroku hosted app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, csv

I have some csv exported rows of data that I need to load into a Rails 2.3.8 app.

The csv data is already in the perfect format for the app that I'm hosting on Heroku.
Is there an easy way to do it?

Thanks,
Augusto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Ruby's built-in CSV library to read your data into an array, which you can then do whatever you need to with:

```
CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |row|
  # use row here...
  # For example, if you had users in a CSV file like "username,email" you could do:
  User.create(:username => row[0], :email => row[1])
end
```

Comment: Sounds exactly what I wanted but when I try to run it in the console I get this:

Comment: NameError: uninitialized constant CSV
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing_not_from_s3_library'
 from /Users/phishman/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206:in `const_missing'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
 from (irb):4

Comment: I found that I need before: "require 'csv'"

Comment: Still I cannot access the file: I'm sure I'm not getting the path right.  The file is in "/public/csv/comments_narranti.csv" but ruby doesn't find it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming it's a one-time thing to load this, you'll need to access the full path, not relative path... so something like `/home/augusto/my_rails_app/public/csv/comments_narranti.csv`

Answer (score 4):

I have had success with something like this:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach(Rails.root.to_s+"/db/calseed_test1.csv") do |row|
Calevent.create(
:caldate => row[0],
:caltime => row[1], 
:callocation => row[2],
:caldescription => row[3]
)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a very simple way.

1. Upload the file to gist or anywhere publically accessible.
2. Use open-uri to load it in any console of your choice.

   csv_file = open('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gauravsaini23/84f9592bbc7cf444e869f8c67321a086/raw/84f7dc0c9d0770a30d28072e05527d1071870042/sample.csv') {|f| f.read}
3. You have all your required data.

   csv = CSV.new(csv_file)
   pry(main)> csv.first
   => ["Name", " Purpose"]